# how to read only positive values from data file

Tags: arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements, idl

i am new to IDL. I have a data file consists of 4 column, 96 rows (saved as new.dat). I am trying to read values only if 2nd column is positive but unable to do it.compiling well but getting no output.Help, please???

```
data=fltarr(4,96)
openr,1,'new.dat'
openw,2,'file.dat'
readf,1,data
for i=0,95 do begin
if (data(1,*) ge 0) then printf,2, data 
endfor
close,/all
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several things to mention here.

First, when you index an array in IDL you should use `[]` instead of `()` to avoid confusion and compiling errors.

Second, in your statement
`if (data(1,*) ge 0) then printf,2, data`
you are trying to print the entire data file for every time your test in your IF statement is satisfied.

Third, you did not specify a `FORMAT` statement for your `READF` statement, which should be done.

Fourth, are you trying to index the second dimension of the array `data`?  If so, you need to use `i` in the `FOR` loop.

Fifth, would it be easier to just read in the data and use it?  A [4,96]-element array is incredibly small and would take a fraction of a second to read in each time you need it.  Then you could use the `WHERE` routine to determine which elements are greater than zero.  For instance, you could try (in the `FOR` loop):
`good = WHERE(data[*,i] GE 0,gd)`
where the variable `good` would contain all the indices satisfying the test statement.

Sixth, I should say that you can and should use `WHERE` without using a `FOR` loop here.  You can just do the following:
`good = WHERE(data GE 0,gd)`
and the variable `good` will contain only elements of `data` ≥ 0.  To index `data`, you need only do something similar to the following:
`data_pos = data[good]`
If you want to keep the new variable `data_pos` the same dimensions as `data`, then you could use the `ARRAY_INDICES` routine in IDL and leave the rest of the indices of `data_pos` as some dummy value you define and know not to be used later.

Comment: I should also point out that you should use `FREE_LUN` instead of `CLOSE` for closing files in IDL.  The former frees the logical unit number or LUN in IDL and does so cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code might become much easier if you use "`readcol`", from http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/pro/misc/readcol.pro

Here is a sample code:

```
openw, filenumber, 'file.dat', /get_lun
readcol, 'new.dat', data0, data1, data2, data3, count=num_read
for i=0,num_read-1 do begin
    if data1[i] gt 0 then printf,2, data2[i] 
endfor
free_lun, filenumber
```

Another code is:

```
openw, lun,'file.dat', /get_lun
readcol, 'new.dat', data0, data1, data2, data3, count=num_read
select = where(data1 gt 0, num_select)
for i=0,num_select-1 do printf,2, data2[i] 
free_lun, lun
```

Note that it is better to use /get_lun while opening files, so that you do not have to manually keep track of open logical unit numbers while coding.